# Understanding the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(-D)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}\rightarrow k_D\rightarrow0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface, let $p\in X$, and for a positive integer $n$, let $D=np$ denote an effective divisor on $X$. we define $k_D$ to be the skyscraper sheaf at $p$ with stalk $\mathbb{C}^n$. By $\mathcal{O}(D)$ I mean the sheaf of sections of the line bundle corresponding to $D$.
I am having difficulty understanding the following :

*claim*: there exists a short exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(-D)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}\rightarrow k_D\rightarrow0$.

For the justification of its existence, the author says:
"The exactness follows from the fact that any local holomorphic function can be represented around $p$ in the Taylor form $f(z)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{f^{(k)}(z)}{k!}(z-p)^k + (z-p)^n.g(z)$. Then the term $(z-p)^ng(z)$ is a section of $\mathcal{O}(-D)$, while the first term gives a section of $k_D$."

My doubts:

i) Can someone please explain what the actual maps are in the exact sequence?
ii)How can we consider $(z-p)^ng(z)$ as a section of $\mathcal{O}(-D)$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If $P\in U$, the space of sections of $k_D$ over $U$ is $\Bbb C^n$.
If $f\in\mathcal{O}(U)$ then it maps to say $(f(P),f'(P),f''(P)/2,\ldots,f^{(n-1)}(P)/(n-1)!)$.

The map $\mathcal{O}(-D)\to\mathcal{O}$ is just inclusion.

Here $f\in\mathcal{O}(U)$ for some open $U\ni P$. Then $(z-P)^n
\in\mathcal{O}(-D)(U)$ since it is holomorphic with a zero of order $\ge n$
at $P$.

Comment: Can you kindly explain why the holomorphic sections of $\mathcal{O}(-D)$ exactly correspond to the holomorphic functions with a zero of order $\geq n$ at $p$?

Comment: @yojusmath That is pretty much the definition of $\mathcal{O}(-nP)$.